# veryThick not in scope

Tags: haskell

I am trying the Diagrams module in Haskell. But I can't get ghc to compile the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine

main = mainWith (example :: Diagram B R2)

example = circle 1 # fc blue
                   # lw veryThick
                   # lc purple
```

The problem is, veryThick is not in scope. Though the doc [here](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-TwoD-Attributes.html) says that it is in Diagrams.TwoD.Attributes, it isn't there. Where is veryThick defined and why is there an inconsistency in the doc?

EDIT:

I added

```
import Diagrams.TwoD.Attributes
```

and I get this error.

```
DiagramsTutorial.hs:5:8:
Could not find module `Diagrams.TwoD.Attributes'
Perhaps you meant Diagrams.Attributes (from diagrams-lib-1.1.0.7)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Comment: Why do you say it isn't there? (I mean, it isn't obvious to me that you've imported `Diagrams.TwoD.Attributes`; though I suppose perhaps you believe one of the two modules you imported re-exports it...?) Also, what version of `diagrams-lib` do you have installed?

Comment: As seen in that error message, the version is 1.1.0.7

Comment: in the left top corner of document which you pointed, it has `diagrams-lib-1.2`, so it does not match the version you are using. see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.1.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have Diagrams version 1.1.0.7 installed.  Be sure you are reading the haddocks for the version you are using, not the latest.  If you want to use module `Diagrams.TwoD.Attribuites` then uninstall your current version and install version 1.2.0.1.  Otherwise, you'll have to do without the `veryThick` function as version 1.1.0.7 [doesn't include such a function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.1.0.7/docs/doc-index-V.html).

EDIT: Roughly, the re-installation procedure should involve unregistering your old library (optional but strongly recommended) and installing the new one:

```
ghc-pkg unregister diagrams-core --force
ghc-pkg unregister diagrams-lib
ghc-pkg unregister diagrams-svg
ghc-pkg unregister diagrams-contrib
ghc-pkg unregister diagrams
ghc-pkg list | grep diagrams
# ^^^ should not list any packages!  Unregister any remaining packages
cabal update
cabal install diagrams-lib-1.2.0.1
cabal install diagrams-svg
```